# Is there a limit to how many "../" back-directory references you can make?

Tags: linux, bash

I've never noticed this before (and I've been using Linux as a primary OS since 2008). Is there a limit to how many back-directory references you can make with `../`?

Why?

I moved a file only for it to disappear. And now I'm trying to target a Java command and testing `ls ../`, I can only see back 3 directories but not 4.

Comment: I just tested, ls ../../../../../ worked perfectly well. It seems to be something funky in your setup.

Comment: Rookie mistake. I'm not used to working with these Java files. After kestasx mentioned it, I found this was the problem. Normal Linux files that I deal with (web file and sysconfig in etc) don't use so many symlinks. It just never happened before.

Comment: Haha :D That's good to know just in case. Happy holidays anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hard limit I'm aware of is `PATH_MAX`, you can check it (for current folder, value is filesystem dependent):

```
getconf PATH_MAX .
```

I would guess some of path elements were symlinks, and Your file was moved into "unexpected" folder. You should be able to find it by name or content.

Try another shell (`tcsh`, `sh`, ... ) as there may be some shell configuration, which is the reason (aliases, ...).

Software bugs are also possible, but not likely for 2-3 levels...

Comment: Symlinks! This Java app is lousy with em. Thanks.